# How to run external program(exe, bat) withing casperjs script

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have running casperjs program, i want during the script to wait for a few seconds and run exe file. it can be .bat as well. and then read the result from text file. as far as i know my only problem right now is to execute the external exe from the caseper program. i notice there is a solution for shell with a child process but how to do it on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Find it! Maybe it will help someone...

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    var test = function(){
           console.log("test is running");
           exec('huh.exe', function(err, ans)
                {
                    console.log(err)
                console.log(ans.toString());
                });  
    }
test();
```

Comment: Oh, it was just the code when I wrote my comment and I thought you just showed what you tried, now I understand that it's the actual answer after your last edit. Sorry about that